# Using Tinymce with Elfinder

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce

I read this post on [http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=26653](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWj2H.jpg) on how to integrate Elfinder filemanager with Tinymyce, It worked but not completely.

The issue is after browsing and uploading an image, it doesn't pick the image URL link from the Elfinder filemanager this is the code i tried using

In TinyMCE init, I added this

```
 file_browser_callback : function(field_name, url, type, win) {
   var cmsURL = 'fullpath/elfinder/elfinder.php';    // script URL - use an absolute path!
            if (cmsURL.indexOf("?") < 0) {
                //add the type as the only query parameter
                cmsURL = cmsURL + "?type=" + type;
            }
            else {
                //add the type as an additional query parameter
                // (PHP session ID is now included if there is one at all)
                cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=" + type;
            }

            tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
                file : cmsURL,
                title : 'elFinder 2.0',
                width : 900,  
                height : 450,
                resizable : "yes",
                inline : "yes",  // This parameter only has an effect if you use the inlinepopups plugin!
                popup_css : false, // Disable TinyMCE's default popup CSS
                close_previous : "no"
            }, {
                window : win,
                input : field_name
            });
            return false;
        }
```

In elfinder.html, i add the following to elfinder initialisation:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $().ready(function() {
            var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder({

                url : 'php/connector.php',  
                getfile : {
                    onlyURL : true,
                    multiple : false,
                    folders : false
                },
                getFileCallback : function(url) {
                    path = url.path;
                    FileBrowserDialogue.mySubmit(path);
                }                     
            }).elfinder('instance');            
        });

    </script>
```

I just need to grab the url source of a selected image and put it inside Tinymyce image link

For Example:

[image: Image Url locator of Tinymyce]

Comment: is there an accessible live example of this? maybe a tinymce fiddle?